# External resources in JSFiddle (Adding Twitter Bootstrap CDN)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsfiddle

I am trying to replicate my issue with [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) but when needed frameworks not supported natively, I believe I will need to import them from **external resources**. However, clicking <kbd>+</kbd> won't open up anything and I am not sure what to do with the URI field.

The simple question is, I particularly need to embed Bootstrap.

How do I embed Bootstrap in JSFiddle?

Comment: You put the url of the resource in the textbox then you click the `+`

Comment: Thanks, but the question is how do I make Bootstrap externally available? Do I need to host it somewhere? Unlike jQuery, I don't know if Bootstrap CDN is supported...

Comment: This is a meta-question, if I ever saw one. Just saying...

Comment: No, @nickhar, I didn't mean that it belonged on meta, I meant that it seemed to be a question about a question, given that it opens "I am trying to replicate ..." but now that I'm re-reading it it's not :)

Comment: Visit http://www.webgetway.com/bootstrap, you will find CDN there: under installation

Answer (score 59, accepted):

BootstrapCDN is supported by JSFiddle, you just need to paste in the relevant URLs.

In the external resource field/box enter each of these URLs* and hit <kbd>+</kbd>:

```
http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css
http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

The result of which is: http://jsfiddle.net/v9ec3/1/

Which then allows you to post your HTML/CSS/JS as required. Edit away and click `update` when finished to give you a URL that you can paste anywhere (including here!). Note you don't need to reference it via link.

****Note:** The above bootstrap version URLs (2.3.2) are pasted from http://www.bootstrapcdn.com at the time of the question*

Comment: One other simple question if you don't mind, how do I get the fiddle link without my account name (making it public?) I tried to add title and description to make it public but makes no difference...

Comment: Sure, for anonymity and if you have a JSFiddle account, just logout, create a new fiddle and you can modify as many times as you wish, update and then post the URL anywhere. Does this help?

Answer (score 4):

Use Https instead of http as it jsfiddle allows only https. Please check it down here

https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css
https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js

Answer (score 2):

For a more general solution to this (not only Bootstrap but many other JavaScript libraries), I found [cdnjs](https://cdnjs.com/) very helpful:
Go to cdnjs, search for your library, copy the URl and paste it in the "External Resources" field of your fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I do something like this: `@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');`

Answer (score 0):

you can look this example my jsFiddle [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AnjasmaraDwiSetiadi/d4rc8ovj/25/)
it is easy you want add cdn like jquery, bootstrap bulma etc. you want add bootstrap v5 cdn, you just look on sidebar with name "Resources" it have label 'URL','cdnjs' . click it and `+` .

1. then search bootstrap you can select version
2. or you can paste manual cdn below if you want another version or another cdn. cdn below for bootstrap v5.2.

   [https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css%22)

   https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js