# Bootstrap 4 row columns not breaking row

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create a bootstrap grid where every row has to columns, bootstrap has a class that does this, row-cols-*, but when I place the example on bootstrap [website](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/#row-columns) in a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7u65agnj/16/) it doesn't break row like it is supposed to do. What am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row row-cols-2 text-white">
    <div class="col border bg-primary">Column</div>
    <div class="col border bg-primary">Column</div>
    <div class="col border bg-primary">Column</div>
    <div class="col border bg-primary">Column</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.row-cols-*` class is new to Bootstrap 4.4: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases. Your problem might be due to the fact that you're referencing the prior version of Bootstrap. At least your jsfiddle was doing that.

Reference the correct Bootstrap 4.4 files fixes the issue:

[image]

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/1Ltc9zos/1/

[image]

Comment: Thank you, really helped me, was using 4.3.1

Answer (score 0):

[External resources in JSFiddle (Adding Twitter Bootstrap CDN)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17478396/external-resources-in-jsfiddle-adding-twitter-bootstrap-cdn)

The logic is the same as when you set it up in an editor, like Brackets.

Try this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row row-cols-2">
    <div class="col">Column</div>
    <div class="col">Column</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row row-cols-2">
    <div class="col">Column</div>
    <div class="col">Column</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem isn't that bootstrap isn't loading, other bootstrap classes like bg-primary is working